# Predict nested model with nested newdata

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, time-series, predict

Imagine a high resolution temperature and light time series taken at many locations (stations) over many days. Except, at each station temp and light are taken by different sensors, resulting in a slightly different set of timestamps.

To merge these into one `data.frame`, I've been trying to make a model of light for each day at each station in `df.light`. Then, I want to predict light values at the exact timestamps of temp readings, which are nested the same way in `df.temp` (the temperature dataset).

```
station <- rep(1:5, each=36500)
dayofyear <- rep(1:365, 5, each=100)

hourofday.light <- runif(182500, min=0, max=24)
light <- runif(182500, min=0, max=40)

hourofday.temp <- runif(182500, min=0, max=24)
temp <- runif(182500, min=0, max=40)

df.light <- data.frame(station, dayofyear, hourofday.light, light)    
df.temp <- data.frame(station, dayofyear, hourofday.temp, temp)

> head(df.light)
  station dayofyear hourofday.light     light
1       1         1       10.217349  0.120381
2       1         1       12.179213 12.423694
3       1         1       16.515400  7.277784
4       1         1        3.775723 31.793782
5       1         1        7.719266 30.578220
6       1         1        9.269916 16.937042
> tail(df.light)
       station dayofyear hourofday.light      light
182495       5       365        4.712285 19.2047471
182496       5       365       11.190919 39.5921675
182497       5       365       18.710969 11.8182347
182498       5       365       20.288101 11.6874453
182499       5       365       15.466373  0.3264828
182500       5       365       12.969125 29.4429034
> head(df.temp)
  station dayofyear hourofday.temp      temp
1       1         1     12.1298554 30.862308
2       1         1     23.6226076  9.328942
3       1         1      9.3699831 28.970397
4       1         1      0.1814767  1.405557
5       1         1     23.6300014 39.875743
6       1         1      7.6999984 39.786182
```

I can make the light models, e.g. GAMs, for each day at each station in `df.light` using `dplyr`. But I am stuck not knowing how to feed the nested `newdata` from `df.temp` to the models to generate the per-station-per-day predictions.

```
library("mgcv")
library("tidyverse")

data <- as_tibble(df.light) %>%
  group_by(station, dayofyear) %>%
  nest()

models <- data %>%
  mutate(
    model = map(data, ~ gam(light ~ s(hourofday.light), data = .x)),
    predicted = map(model, ~ predict.gam(.x, newdata = hourofday.temp)) # newdata doesn't look nested
  )
```

The last line starting with `predicted` **does not work** because newdata is not nested...I think. Please help. I'm guessing this could be a common issue in merging time series generated by multiple sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can first prepare the data.

```
names(df.temp)[3:4] <- names(df.light)[3:4]
data1 <- df.light %>% group_by(station, dayofyear) %>%nest() %>% ungroup()
data2 <- df.temp %>% group_by(station, dayofyear) %>% nest() %>% ungroup()
```

apply model and get predicted values.

```
result <- data1 %>%
            mutate(data2 = data2$data,
                   model = map(data, ~ gam(light ~ s(hourofday.light),data = .x)),
                   predicted = map2(model, data2, predict.gam))


result
# A tibble: 1,825 x 6
#   station dayofyear data               data2              model  predicted  
#     <int>     <int> <list>             <list>             <list> <list>     
# 1       1         1 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 2       1         2 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 3       1         3 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 4       1         4 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 5       1         5 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 6       1         6 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 7       1         7 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 8       1         8 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# 9       1         9 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
#10       1        10 <tibble [100 × 2]> <tibble [100 × 2]> <gam>  <dbl [100]>
# … with 1,815 more rows
```